# Is it possible to develop for Windows Phone 7.5 in VS11 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

I'm about to start working on a Windows Phone project which targets Windows Phone 7.5.

For other projects, I use Visual Studio 11, but when I try to load the WP 7 projects, they show up as unavailable. Apparently, they are "*...incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio*" (the message I get when hovering over the project nodes in the solution explorer).

I am able to open the projects in Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone (available [from this page](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) along with the 7.1 SDK package), but I would really prefer to work in VS11. I find it hard to believe that there is no way to do this, yet I have not been able to find any clear answers;

Any pointers or ideas on how to make VS11 support WP 7 projects in Windows 7 (if it is at all possible) would be appreciated.

**Update:** I forgot to mention one critical detail: I am using Windows 7, which prohibits me from using the Windows 8 SDK (which requires Windows 8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can develop Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 applications in same IDE — Visual Studio 2012. Just [download](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) and install **SDK 8.0**.

**UPDATE:** On Windows 7 please try this solution:

1. Download all files of [this folder](https://github.com/Xlab/wp8sdk-installer/tree/master/bin) on git-hub
2. Drag `WPexpress_full.exe` and drop it on `wp8sdk_installer.exe`
   [image]
3. Follow the White Rabbit

But be prepare for some bad news:

- Windows Phone 8 emulator doesn't work
- Blend for Windows Phone 8  doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Apparently I forgot to mention that I am on windows 7 for the time being, which means the Windows 8 SDK is not an option. I'll update my question...

Comment: Thanks again for both the effort and the answer. :) I'll give this a try.

Comment: For the record: I tried this, and it seems to have installed correctly, but I still could not load the existing (WP7.5) projects into VS11. They remained "incompatible". It might have been possible to work with WP8 projects on Windows 7 though - I never got around to trying that, but the SDK for WP8 did appear to work. In the end, I just switched to Windows 8; ta-da, problem solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this [does not seem to be possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Citing the linked page:

```
Windows Phone: You can’t open this project in Visual Studio 2012 
               because it doesn't support the project type.
```

I'm assuming this will change once we switch to Windows 8, and are able to use the Windows 8 SDK, as andrewpey mentioned.